# How to deal with null EditText value in Android?

Tags: android, null, crash, android-edittext

I'm developing an app for android, and currently the only thing it does is calculate grades. There's two input boxes, one that takes the current grade, and another that takes a possible exam grade, and then it tells you the final grade. However, when there is no value in at least one of those boxes, it crashes. I tried to make an if statement to detect if the final value was null, but that didn't work. Here's my code:

```
public void sendMessage(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    EditText grade = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.grade1);
    EditText exam = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.grade2);
    String stringGrade = (grade.getText().toString());
    String stringExam = (exam.getText().toString());
    double finalResult = (Double.parseDouble(stringGrade) * .8) + (Double.parseDouble(stringExam) * 0.2);
    String finalResultString = String.valueOf(finalResult);
    if (finalResultString == null){
        finalResultString = "0";
    } else {
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, finalResultString);
    startActivity(intent);
}}
```

and here's the code that renders it:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

    TextView textView1 = new TextView(this);
    textView1.setTextSize(30);
    textView1.setText("Your final would be " + message);

    setContentView(textView1);
```

Just for reference, the .8 and .2 is because the current grade is weighted at 80%, and the exam is weighted at 20%. How can I make it so it won't crash when nothing is put into the boxes?

Comment: test if *stringGrade* and *stringExam* not equals to "" before calculating *finalResult*

Comment: Thanks a lot! That fixed the problem. For future reference, you have to use !stringExam.equals("") instead of stringExam != "".

Comment: Please if you fixed the problem, accept one answer or add your solution as an answer for future reference.

Comment: If you have not yet. Also add this attribute to EditText
android:inputType="number"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`usernameEditText.getText().toString();` would not return null. It will return an empty string. What you can do before calculating `finalResult` is to check stringGrade and stingExam are non-empty and numerical values and if one is not then stop the operation. i.e.

```
String stringGrade = (grade.getText().toString());
String stringExam = (exam.getText().toString());

if (stringGrade.isEmpty() || stringExam.isEmpty()) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Invalid values", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
public void sendMessage(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    EditText grade = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.grade1);
    EditText exam = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.grade2);
    String stringGrade = (grade.getText().toString());
    String stringExam = (exam.getText().toString());
    if(stringGrade.equals("") ){
       stringGrade = "0";
    }
    if(stringExam.equals("") ){
       stringExam= "0";
    }
    double finalResult = (Double.parseDouble(stringGrade) * .8) + (Double.parseDouble(stringExam) * 0.2);
    String finalResultString = String.valueOf(finalResult);
    if (finalResultString == null){
        finalResultString = "0";
    } else {
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, finalResultString);
    startActivity(intent);
}}
```